# Blazor server app calling multiple API - Consent handling

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have Blazor server app using .net 7.0 which calls graph api and couple of other API that requires user consent.
They have been configured using following code in startup.cs.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()                
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddDownstreamApi("DelegatedAPI", config.GetSection("AP1"))
.AddDownstreamApi("AnotherAPI", config.GetSection("AP2"))
```

How do we get the user consent for all the API at once. Right now I am getting incremental consent error everytime when I try to run the application.

Any solution?

Comment: Do you want user consent to be a manual flow or just implicitly granted?

Comment: Either option is fine. Would like to try both.

Comment: Added an answer around implicit consent. If you want the incremental answer, you’ll need to post more about your Azure AD setup (incl. app registration) and also the specific error you’re seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to simply grant administrator consent ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal#grant-admin-consent-in-app-registrations)) on the application registration to your downstream APIs. This will bypass any need for users themselves to consent, but may not be appropriate for every use case. You can find out more about either incremental consent, conditional consent, or static consent [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access#static-permissions).

Comment: Thanks. Above links helped to create a static consent and it resolved the issue.